# Importing CSV values with custom number formatting

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with a timestamp column that has a custom number formatting in this format mm:ss.0.

I am trying to change that custom number formatting to h:mm:ss AM/PM, preferably during the Import-CSV command, but it doesn't have to be.

For example, 42:00.5 should be 12:42:00 AM.

Most of the examples I've seen had dates and times and could easily be converted using ToString and Get-Date but I couldn't get those examples working with just a time stamp.

Here's a few examples of what I've tried:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | 
    Select *,@{label = 'timestamp';expression={get-date $_.Date -f 'h:mm:ss tt'}} -ExcludeProperty timestamp | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation foo2.cs

Import-Csv foo.csv | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'timestamp'; Expression = { '{h:mm:ss tt}' -f [datetime]$_.'timestamp' }}, * -ExcludeProperty 'timestamp' | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation foo2.csv
```

What am I missing?

This is where I would go in Excel to change the custom number format. The selected is what the current number format is and the highlighted is what I need.

[image]

Comment: In your example _"42:00.5 should be 12:42:00"_, how do you come up with the hour? Does the input time contain minutes since 12:00 am, e. g. "61:00.5" should become "01:01:00"?

Comment: The format mm:ss.0 cannot express all the times in a day.  The format is likely to be different from that.

Comment: @zett42 I got the hour from the formula bar, when I select the cell, the cell shows 42:00.5 but the formula bar in Excel shows 12:42:00 AM.

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm not sure, I posted a screen shot of the custom number format menu in Excel. This is what I'm trying to change.

Comment: maybe it's really 00:42:00.5